# Notify when all onCreateViewHolder inside a RecylerView have finished

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

RecyclerView calls onCreateViewHolder a bunch of times and then just keeps binding the data to these views. My view creation is slightly expensive and hence I need to defer rest of the UI tasks until my RecyclerView is done creating all the views.

I tried adding a `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` but this callback gets called before even the first `onCreateViewHolder()` call.

Any idea how do I go about it?

Comment: "My view creation is slightly expensive" -- I would focus on fixing this instead. `onLayoutCompleted()` of a custom `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` might get called at your desired point in time, but I would only go down that path as a last resort.

Comment: Tbh, I'm not really able to solve the view inflation problem. I have some Dagger 2 component.inject() calls in my views. Not sure if they are messing it up.

Comment: "I'm not really able to solve the view inflation problem" -- use method tracing to determine where your problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I've found out a solution with `Handler`. As you I'm looking for a beautiful code and this is a bit messy for me. But works perfectly anyway.

`Handler` is a class that you can use in a way to post message and/or Runnable, which will be added in a queue, then executed when that queue is finished.

My plan is, given that the adapter works on the UI, (inflate ect...) the creation and initialization (all `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder`) are added at a moment in the handler of the main thread.

That means that if you post a message in the main thread queue (the same obligatory used by your adapter), then the message will be executed after any previous request (after your adapted has finished to initialize everything).

## Exemple :

### Main activity

Initialization of the handler :

```
private Handler mHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle iSavedInstanceState) {
     ...
     mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
}
```

Initialization of your CustomAdapter :

```
private void initializeAdapter(...) {
    MyCustomAdapter lMyNewAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(...)
    ...

    lNewAdapter.SetOnFirstViewHolderCreation(new 
         MyCustomAdapter.OnFirstViewHolderCreation {

             @Override
             public void onCreation() {

                  mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                           // Finally here, the code you want to execute
                           // At the end of any Create and Bind VH of your
                           // Adapter 
                      }
                  });
             }

    });
}
```

### MyCustomAdapter

```
private boolean mIsViewHolderCreationStarted;
private OnFirstViewHolderCreation mOnFirstViewHolderCreation;

public CustomItemViewAdapter onCreateViewHolder(
     @NonNull ViewGroup iViewGroup, int iI) {

     ...
     if (!mIsViewHolderCreationStarted) {
          mIsViewHolderCreationStarted = true;

          if (mOnFirstViewHolderCreation != null) {
               // It's at this point that we want to add a new request
               // in the handler. When we're sure the request of the
               // adapter has begun.
               mOnFirstViewHolderCreation.onCreation();
          }
     }
}

public void setOnFirstViewHolderCreation(OnFirstViewHolderCreation iAction) {
    mOnFirstViewHolderCreation = iAction;
}

public interface OnFirstViewHolderCreation {
    void onCreation();
}
```

## Note

Be aware that this solution will execute a code at the end of the first initialization of the enteer page that it is possible to show in a case of a RecyclerView.
A `onCreateViewHolder` might be called in case the screen is scrolled.
Which means that this solution does not guarantee you this handler message is executed after all possible `onCreateViewHolder`.
It only helps you to avoid an overload on the MainThread, during the greedy work of the adapter init.

Something else, in case you're using animations with your adapter to make it appears smoothly or something else (one of the good reasons to use this way to do), don't forget to put your RecyclerView in `VISIBLE` and not `GONE`, otherwise, the initialization of the adapter never happens.